# Closing gap between elements when visibility:hidden

Tags: javascript, html

How do I close the gap between elements if I hide a few of them with `visibility: hidden`?

I have this HTML.

```
    <div id="logged_in" style="display:inline; visibility: hidden;"><a onclick=""></a>&nbsp;&#8226;&nbsp;</div>
    <a id="login_box" onclick="show_login_user();">Login</a>
    <a id="logout_box" onclick="logout_user();" style="visibility: hidden;">Logout</a>&nbsp;|&nbsp;
    <a onclick="show_register_user();">Register</a>&nbsp;|&nbsp;
```

When the user is logged out, logout is hidden and there is a gap between login and register.  If the user is logged in, there is a gap between the `logged_in` username and logout.

Comment: really need to see more, like maybe for full css of that region and anything that might be around it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `display:none;` instead. `visibility:hidden;` does not "free" the space used by the hidden element.

Comment: oh yeah, ddnt noticed that, he's totally right! listen to this answer!

Comment: use css to set it's display inline, so that the style apply can be display none, and on show it'll be inline

Comment: @SpYk3HH: That's not needed, you can use `display:none` on the element without having any `display` style in the css. And the links are display inline by default by the way.

Comment: I set `display:none;` in the style and in the code set `display:inline` to show the element.  This works.